# Troubles with server.php

Tags: javascript, php, html

Maybe someone knows, I want to receive the data entered by the user and I use PCP as a server, but the code does not go through - " request.send(formData) ", it says " Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed) ", what could be the reason for this behavior? I add the code:

```
const inputName = document.getElementById('name')
const inputTel = document.getElementById('tel')
const clickBtn = document.getElementById('submit')
const forms = document.querySelector('form')


addForm(forms)


function addForm (form){
form.addEventListener(('submit'), (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();

    const statusMessage = document.createElement('div')
    statusMessage.innerHTML = '';
    statusMessage.innerHTML = 'Loading'
    forms.append(statusMessage)

    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('POST', 'server.php');
    // request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'multipart/form-data')
    const formData = new FormData(form)
    request.send(formData)

    request.addEventListener(('load'), () => {
        statusMessage.innerHTML = ''
        if (request.status === 200) {
            console.log(request.response)
            statusMessage.innerHTML = 'Loading success'
        } else{
            statusMessage.innerHTML = 'Something went wrong'
        }
    })
})
}
```

```
<?php
echo var_dump($_POST);
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>coffe-house</title>
    <style>
        body{
            background-color: rgb(88, 0, 88);
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 100vw;
            min-height: 100vh;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        .forma{
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 400px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items:center;
            padding: 60px 0;
            background-color: rgba(0, 255, 247, 0.5);
            border-radius: 10px;
        }
        form{
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            row-gap: 30px;
        }
        input{
            border-radius: 5px;
            outline: none;
            border: none;
            padding: 5px;
        }
        #submit{
            padding: 10px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="forma">
    <form>
            <input id="name" type="text" name="name">
            <input id="tel" type="tel" name="tel">
        <button id="submit">Click here</button>
    </form>
</div>
<script src="./index.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a problem with your webserver configuration, not a JS or PHP problem.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for viewing. And you know how to fix it. I am using VS code live server. –

Comment: You can't run php just with that server, it only works with simple static sites. Use a proper webserver like Apache or IIS